# Segmentaion fault in C

Tags: c, pointers

As a part of training I m learning this pointer to pointer concept.
But I am getting a segmentation fault while running this.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Below is the code snippet:

```
main()
{
  int *ptr;
  init(&ptr);
  printf(" %d \n",*ptr);
}

init( int **p_ptr)
{
    **p_ptr=56;
}
```

but the following init () function works well.

```
init( int **p_ptr)
{
    int i=56
    **p_ptr=&i;
}
```

Comment: `ptr` doesn't point to anything, so trying to write to `**(&ptr)` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for the variable that the pointer points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int *ptr;` is a pointer to an interger, but you never initialized it. The value of `ptr`is not defined so this is undefined behavior. To make your code work, the value of `ptr` has to be an address of a variable with type `int`. `*ptr` and `**p_ptr` tries to read the value where `ptr` refers to and this causes the segmentation fault. Adapt your code like this:

```
main()
{
  int myInt;               // local varibale myInt
  int *ptr = &myInt;       // pointer ptr refers to local varibale myInt
  init(&ptr);              // pass pointer to ptr to function init
  printf(" %d \n",*ptr);
}
```

Note in function `init`, `p_ptr` now is a pointer to `ptr` and so a pointer to a pointer to `myInt`.

Of course you can allocate dynamic memory too:

```
#include <malloc.h>

main()
{
    int *ptr = &myInt = malloc( sizeof( int ) ); // ptr refers to dynamicly allocated memory
    init(&ptr);             
    printf(" %d \n",*ptr);
    free( ptr );                                 // free the dynamic memory
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of, please edit your message so the code can be well displayed (read the help documentation to know how to do this).

In C, a pointer is assigned an **address**, when in your second function you assign the pointer `&i` you assign `i`'s address (but it shouldn't work because `i` is detroyed at the end of the function because it's a local variable). When you do `**p_ptr=56;` you're trying to assign to the pointer the address 56 which you probably don't have access to, and that's why you get the segmentation fault.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the pointer is pointing nowhere, you have to assign memory to be pointed at.

```
    int myInt;
    int *myPtr = &MyInt
```

Or:

```
    int *myPtr= (int *) malloc (sizeof(int));
```

EDIT: I've been watching the second alternative and it is even more undefined as the var i doesn't exist outside the function, so the memory that hold i is not reserved for you anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your examples are wrong.  The first one fails because you haven't initialized `ptr` to point to allocated storage.  You can fix it with:

```
int i;
int *ptr = &i;
```

The second example is even more wrong, assuming you're calling it the same way.  You're assigning through an undefined pointer.  The behavior is undefined.